# Map an object with multiple properties to another and then collect to list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an object like this one:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
}
```

And another one, let's call it:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class DBPerson {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
}
```

Assume both objects have a constructor with `name` and `lastName` and their respective getters and setters, I'm using `lombok`

```
List<DBPerson> dbPersons = new ArrayList();
dbPersons.add(new DBPerson("Harry", "Potter"));
dbPersons.add(new DBPerson("Hermione", "Granger"));
dbPersons.add(new DBPerson("Ronald", "Weasley"));
```

I need to convert from a `List<DBPerson>` to `List<Person>`, so I tried this way:

```
dbPersons.stream()
.map(DBPerson::getName)
.map(Person::new)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This obviously is giving me an error on `new` because there's no constructor with a single `String` on `Person` class

How could I map both properties of `DBPerson` to create a new `Person` and then collect all of those into a `List<Person>`?

I've tried with `.forEach`, however I'm not sure it would be the most optimal solution, so if there's another way of doing it using Stream API I'll appreciate any better solution, otherwise I'll have to stick with `.forEach`.

I've found other solutions using `flatMap` but those are for concatenating both `name` and `lastName` into a single `String`, which is not what I want.

Comment: You need a regular lambda: `dbPerson -> new Person(dbPerson.getName(), dbPerson.getLastName())`

Comment: Or you can create a constructor `Person(DBPerson dbPerson)` and map `Person::new`.

Comment: Do you mean inside a `.forEach` cycle with a regular lambda? @shmosel Like `dbPersons.forEach(dbPerson -> new Person(...))`?

Comment: No, that goes inside the `map()`.

Comment: Got it, that actually did it, if you could write that as an answer I'd be glad to accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## tl;dr

Add to the second class a constructor that takes an argument of the type of the first class. Use `Stream#map` with a method reference for that constructor, and collect new instances of the second class.

```
personXes.stream().map( PersonY :: new ).toList();
```

## Lambda function

Rather than use method references for your getters, write a lambda function to produce a new object.

Let’s use the Java 16+ [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature for brevity.

```java
package work.basil.mix;

public record PersonX( String firstName , String lastName ) { }
```

```java
package work.basil.mix;

public record PersonY( String firstName , String lastName ) { }
```

Get some sample data.

```java
List < PersonX > xList =
        List.of(
                new PersonX( "Harry" , "Potter" ) ,
                new PersonX( "Hermione" , "Granger" ) ,
                new PersonX( "Ronald" , "Weasley" )
        );
```

Make a stream of the elements in that list. For each of those `PersonX` objects, we need to generate a `PersonY` object. For such a transformation, use [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)). The result of our `map` function must match the type of our new collection. In our case that new collection is a `List< PersonY >`. So our transformational `map` function must produce a `PersonY` object.

Lastly, we collect each newly produced `PersonY` into a unmodifiable list by calling `.toList`. Before Java 16, you must use the more verbose `.collect( Collectors.toList() )`.

```java
List < PersonY > yList = xList.stream().map( personX -> new PersonY( personX.firstName() , personX.lastName() ) ).toList() ;
```

In alternate formatting.

```java
List < PersonY > yList =
        xList
                .stream()
                .map(
                        personX -> new PersonY( personX.firstName() , personX.lastName() )
                )
                .toList();
```

When run.

> yList = [PersonY[firstName=Harry, lastName=Potter], PersonY[firstName=Hermione, lastName=Granger], PersonY[firstName=Ronald, lastName=Weasley]]

## Alternate constructor

Another approach is to add a constructor to your second class, taking as an argument an object of the first class. The constructor then extracts the necessary data from the existing object of the first class to construct an object of the second class.

This approach makes sense if you will be doing this conversion often, in an on-going manner.

```java
package work.basil.mix;

public record PersonY( String firstName , String lastName ) {
    public PersonY ( PersonX personX ) {
        this( personX.firstName() , personX.lastName() );
    }
}
```

Now we can simplify our code seen above.

```
List < PersonY > yList = xList.stream().map( personX -> new PersonY( personX ) ).toList();
```

We can further simplify by using a method reference for the constructor: `PersonY :: new`. Each `personX` object will be implicitly passed to the constructor.

This next line of code works exactly the same as the line above, just shorter, not better. In both cases, each streamed object of the first class is being passed to the constructor of the second class.

```
List < PersonY > yList = xList.stream().map( PersonY :: new ).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In java 8

```
    Function<DBPerson, Person> toPersonMapper =
      dbPerson -> new Person(dbPerson.getName(), dbPerson.getLastName());

    List<Person> personList =
      dbPersonList
        .stream()
        .map(toPersonMapper)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```